# PHP match the particular host and file extension and replace if mismatched

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm a newbie in PHP and would like to check if messages posted on my forum contain the correct pattern of an uploaded images. Here are 4 variants of patterns which can only be used:

`http://www.example.com/images/0123456789.FILE_EXT`

`http://www.example.com/images/thumbs/0123456789.jpg`

`http://www.example.com/pictures/_f/f_0123456789.FILE_EXT`

`http://www.example.com/pictures/_t/t_0123456789.jpg`

FILE_EXT can only be JPG, JPEG, GIF or PNG and nothing else. File name in first two patterns is only numeric, in two last patterns is numeric preceded by "t_" or "f_" chars.

Anything which does not match to the above patterns I would like to "str_replace" with an "EXTERNAL LINK" string further in the code. This is to avoid someone to post links to images uploaded to any external server or files uploaded to my server into a different (restricted) directories - I recently discovered that someone can create the link to an image whose size is set to 0-1px (invisible in message), insert that link leading to a remote or restricted content between "img" bbcode tags (eg. |img|http://www.example.com/download/file.php?id=123|/img|) and force people who view such message to download that remote or restricted content without even knowing that.

I have attempted that piece of code which at least replaces all external links:

```
'preg' => array(
    //allow only images from my domain
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/pictures/.*?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/images/.*?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    //text replace all others
    '#\[img:$uid\](.*?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => str_replace('$2', 'External Image', $this->bbcode_tpl('url', $bbcode_id, true)),
)
```

But unfortunately, I can easily cheat the above by inserting the below string between "img" tags:

`http://www.example.com/pictures/../download/file.php?id=123`

This is because those 2 dots between "pictures/" and "/download" escape from "pictures" directory (jump to the parent directory). I've tried some other piece of code to avoid that (added below) but it replaces all images to an "External Image" string, even those matching my patterns:

```
'preg' => array(
    //only allow images from my domain and particular path
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/pictures/_f/f_(/^[0-9]*$/).*?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/pictures/_t/t_(/^[0-9]*$/).jpg?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/images/(/^[0-9]*$/).*?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/images/thumbs/(/^[0-9]*$/).jpg?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    //text replace all others
    '#\[img:$uid\](.*?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => str_replace('$2', 'External Image', $this->bbcode_tpl('url', $bbcode_id, true)),
)
```

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Meh... Just completely messed up with that php regex. Shame on me but at least all of us started from scratch. Here is a fully working code which does exactly what I wanted to achieve:

```
'preg' => array(
    //only allow images from my domain and particular path
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/pictures/_f/f_[0-9]+\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/pictures/_t/t_[0-9]+\.jpg)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/images/[0-9]+\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    '#\[img:$uid\](http://www\.example\.com/images/thumbs/[0-9]+\.jpg)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => $this->bbcode_tpl('img', $bbcode_id),
    //text replace all others
    '#\[img:$uid\](.*?)\[/img:$uid\]#s' => str_replace('$2', 'External Image', $this->bbcode_tpl('url', $bbcode_id, true)),
)
```